# Private key storage rsa node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, security, axios, private-key

I am developing a document sharing application that allows users to send files securely. Currently, I encrypt documents on the server side using encryption (key, IV), then encrypt the key and IV with the recipient's public key. However, I want the encryption to be client-side to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.

I am aware that storing all the information (public key, private key, IV, etc.) on the server side can make my application vulnerable to a data breach, so I am looking for an end-to-end encryption solution.

I am new to this and was wondering if there are any libraries or security protocols I could use to implement this end-to-end encryption method.

What would be the best approaches to implement end-to-end encryption for my application? Are there any specific libraries or security protocols that I could use to enhance the security of my application?

Thank you in advance for your help and advice.